# Gradle throwing error "MANAGE-INVALIDPAYLOAD"

Tags: gradle, marklogic, marklogic-dhf

I am doing deployment using Gradle using command "mlDeploy" it is throwing the below error:

> Executing command
> [com.marklogic.appdeployer.command.cma.DeployConfigurationsCommand]
> with sort order [2147483647]
>
> No resource directory found at:
> /S1/data/MLOperations/ml-datahub/dhf/src/main/ml-config/configurations
>
> No resource directory found at:
> /S1/data/MLOperations/ml-datahub/dhf/src/main/entity-config/configurations
>
> No resource directory found at:
> /S1/data/MLOperations/ml-datahub/dhf/src/main/hub-internal-config/configurations
>
> No resource directory found at:
> /S1/data/MLOperations/ml-datahub/dhf/src/main/azure-config/configurations
>
> No resource directory found at:
> /S1/data/MLOperations/ml-datahub/dhf/src/main/dev-config/configurations
>
> Finished executing command
> [com.marklogic.appdeployer.command.cma.DeployConfigurationsCommand] in
> 0ms
>
> Executing command
> [com.marklogic.hub.deploy.commands.CreateGranularPrivilegesCommand]
> with sort order [2147483647]
>
> Sending XML GET request as user 'svc-dev-deploy' (who should have the
> 'manage-admin' and 'security' roles) to path: /manage/v2/privileges
>
> Checking for existence of resource:
> admin-database-clear-data-hub-STAGING Sending XML GET request as user
> 'svc-dev-deploy' (who should have the 'manage-admin' and 'security'
> roles) to path: /manage/v2/privileges
>
> Found privilege with name of admin-database-clear-data-hub-STAGING, so
> updating at path
> /manage/v2/privileges/admin-database-clear-data-hub-STAGING/properties?kind=execute
> Sending JSON PUT request as user 'svc-dev-deploy' (who should have the
> 'manage-admin' and 'security' roles) to path:
> /manage/v2/privileges/admin-database-clear-data-hub-STAGING/properties?kind=execute
>
> Logging HTTP response body to assist with debugging:
> {"errorResponse":{"statusCode":"400", "status":"Bad Request",
> "messageCode":"MANAGE-INVALIDPAYLOAD",
> "message":"MANAGE-INVALIDPAYLOAD: (err:FOER0000) Payload has errors in
> structure, content-type or values. Privilege action cannot be
> changed."}}
>
> Error occurred while sending PUT request to
> /manage/v2/privileges/admin-database-clear-data-hub-STAGING/properties?kind=execute;
> logging request body to assist with debugging: {   "privilege-name" :
> "admin-database-clear-data-hub-STAGING",   "action" :
> "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/privileges/admin/database/clear/$$database-id(data-hub-STAGING)",
> "kind" : "execute",   "role" : [ "data-hub-admin" ] }

Comment: Is the ` "action" : "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/privileges/admin/database/clear/$$database-id(data-hub-STAGING)"` correct? It almost looks like a placeholder wasn't replaced properly for the database-id value. The error is saying you can't change the action. Double check that you have the correct URI for that action being sent.

Comment: @MadsHansen Thanks for the response, can you please tell me where should i check uri "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/privileges/admin/database/clear/$$database-id"

Comment: @MadsHansen if if deploy it on test-server it is working fine,    2024-03-05T20:15:06.1848317Z Sending JSON PUT request as user 'svc-test-deploy' (who should have the 'manage-admin' and 'security' roles) to path: /manage/v2/privileges/admin-database-clear-data-hub-STAGING/properties?kind=execute
2024-03-05T20:15:06.4846897Z Updated privilege at /manage/v2/privileges/admin-database-clear-data-hub-STAGING/properties?kind=execute

Comment: Proabably also good to mention version of DHF, MarkLogic, Gradle.  It mights also be good to register an issue on the DHF github space

Comment: I got the issue, the execute execute privilege which i had created with URL "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/privileges/admin/database/clear/database-id" so database-id got changed, i had ran mlUndeploy then  manually created the forest and restored the database. my question is in which circumstances database id gets change?

Answer (score 0):

That's a DHF privilege that's being deployed. Check to see if there's a privilege already with the same name via the Admin UI. This error can happen when there's an existing privilege with the same name but it's pointing to a different database.